# What is a "Gaussian mirror"?

Tags: optics, terminology, reflection

What is a [Gaussian mirror](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=gaussian+mirror)? I have seen the term used in a book. Gaussian mirrors are supposed to be free of spherical aberration. But what are they?

Comment: For people landing here from the high-dimensional statistics community, there is an unfortunate coincidence of names going on. I'll leave the physics to the regulars here, but you may be looking instead for the method for false discovery rate control in feature selection, which replaces a feature $X$ in the original design matrix with two features $X^+\equiv X+z$ and $X^-\equiv X-z$, $z$ being a Gaussian vector with IID entries of carefully specified standard deviation. - Preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09761
- Paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2021.1923510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gaussian mirror is a mirror whose surface profile is in the shape of a gaussian function, rather than the more typical spherical surface. Spherical surfaces are easier to manufacture, but don't perfectly focus light (i.e. create "aberrated" images or spots due to their geometric shape).

Comment: In the shape of a gaussian function? So it not really a parabola, I mean, the deviations from quadratic shape are important? Interesting. And this gaussian shape has a focal point?

Comment: To first order, a gaussian is a parabola (exp(±r²) ≈ 1 ± r²) and will thus have the same optical power. Parabolic mirrors are good at imaging a single point (the focus) to infinity without the spherical aberration from normal optics. However, if you want to image more than a single point (or equivalently if any light is off axis), then such a system will actually be very aberrated (specifically coma).

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian mirror is a mirror whose reflectivity changes from the center outwards according a gaussian distribution. The word gaussian has no relation with the mirror surface, it can be even flat.

Comment: Its amazing how little I can find on gaussian mirrors. For instance, how does this guassian-changing reflectivity lead to absence of spherical aberration?

Comment: This answer is talking about a Gaussian **apodized** mirror, which is completely different from a mirror with a Gaussian curvature that the OP is referring to.